# PHP execution returns nothing in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Submitting a value inside an input returns nothing through java-script for some reason, i tried debugging the code, after the js code checks if the submitted text is numbers only, it calls upon the js function and sends a value over to the php file, here are their codes respectively:

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
//connection au serveur
    $code = $_POST['value'];
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('Could not connect to the database because: ' . mysqli_error($db));
    //Pointage vers la base de donnée désirée
    $mydb = mysqli_select_db($db, "phptest");
    //lancer la requete
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT serialsold FROM validserial WHERE serial='" . $_POST['value'] . "'");
    //chercher dans la table
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $solde = $row['serialsold'];
        if ($solde <= 0)
        {
            echo "NULL";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<input id=\"search-form\" class=\"m-wrap\" type=\"text\" value=\"You can buy with: $solde \" readonly required />
                  <select name='currencydd' id='currencydd' onchange=\"compare(this)\">;
                    <option value='mad'>DH</option>;
                    <option value='usd'>$</option>;
                    <option value='eur'>€</option>;
                  </select>
                  <button class=\"btnsucc\"/>";
        }
    } else {
        echo '0';
    }
}
```

JS

```
var previous;
    $('#search-form').tooltip();
    //------------------------------------Buy Stuff----------------------
    $(function () {
        $('#searchbar').bind('submit', function () {
            var value = $('#search-form').val();
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                $.post('search.php', {value: value}, function (data) { //it calls search.php here, yes the file exists
                    if (data == '0')
                    {
                        newTooltip = 'Your Code is Invalid, please try again !';
                        $('#search-form').attr('title', newTooltip).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('setContent').tooltip('show');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#search-form').tooltip('hide').tooltip('destroy');
                        }, 5000);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (data == 'NULL')
                    {
                        newTooltip = 'Your Code Has no debit value, please enter another code !';
                        $('#search-form').attr('title', newTooltip).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('setContent').tooltip('show');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#search-form').tooltip('hide').tooltip('destroy');
                        }, 15000);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#searchdiv").html(data);
                        previous = 'mad';
                    }
                });
                return false; //immediatly returns this
            }
            else {
                newTooltip = 'Please enter numbers ONLY !';
                $('#search-form').attr('title', newTooltip).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('setContent').tooltip('show');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#search-form').tooltip('hide').tooltip('destroy');
                }, 5000);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML references & elements

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchbar" method="post">
<div id="searchdiv">
<input id="search-form" class="m-wrap" type="text" placeholder="Enter your AllBuy Code..." /><button type="submit" name="buy" class="btn blue">buy</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you looked at console, what do you get ?

Comment: @MarkoMackic never thought i could check the console, `POST http://localhost:63342/php/search.php 502 (Bad Gateway)`

Comment: Is your web server running at port 63342? and is search.php located in localhost/php/search.php

Comment: @MarkoMackic The second question is definitly not, because entring that link will lead to a 404, as for the first one, i am running on xampp, how do i check if it's 63342 ?

Comment: It surely isn't, but why your javascript is posting to that port, any other code that could be included? Is your search.php located in same directory as javascript ( html, php that's for page ) ?

Comment: my html (which includes the js code above) is in the same place as my php file, the whole php code is in the OP, this is the full html code: http://pastebin.com/3hhYqxXY

Comment: One mistake I can see is that this expects JSON data, so please try using .success(function(data){}); here you have it, I don't know why this would request at xxxx port..http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/, and what OP means

Comment: @MarkoMackic EDIT: i get this now, didn't do any changes though: `jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/PhP-TesT2/search.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` 2ndEDIT: it only does that in chrome.